# how to make selenium to wait for few seconds after clicking a button

Tags: selenium-rc

can anyone help in this issue:  Im clickin a button, at the end of the case by this:

selcmd.Click(objget3);

after clicking this button the page suddenly closed but i have to see the results so it needs to wait for few sec ter.i used waitforpageload() below the code but no use. how can i code it using selenium.

thanks
chinnu

Answer (score 3):

I don know which language you are usin, this is for python code.
Try this it may help.

```
import time

time.sleep( 5 )
```

Comment: i'm not exposed to c# i thin this may help . Imports System.Threading Thread.Sleep(waitTime) use it after click operation.

Comment: Ross Patterson may be correct cos if the button is used to close the application then nothin can be don and if it s not used to close then use abouve thin det might work.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Click()` closes the page, there's nothing you can do to stop that short of replacing `window.close()` with your own version that delays the closing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with defining some time to wait like :

```
selcmd.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
```

which will wait for 30 secs after clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

//// This is for writing in Java / JUint 4 ////

I've been looking around for a few days and found this. Created a test case in the IDE which paused for 5 seconds then exported it into JUint 4 and found the following technique.

First of all, make sure your method has 'throws Exception':

```
public void thisTest() throws Exception {
    // Test code here
}
```

Then you want to add this line to wait for 5 seconds:

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

The argument for the sleep method is in milliseconds.

Hope this is what you're looking for!

Answer (score 0):

**For .Net >>**

//selenium mentioned below is the ISelenium object you used in your scripts

**Solution 1:**

selenium.SetSpeed("5000");

The above command will wait 5ms before executing the next command.

**Solution 2:**

You can prevent browser from closing after the 'Test' execution if you comment the [TearDown] function.(i.e comment the command selenium.Stop())